# Is there a way to systematically query sqlite3 rows to put the data into a C array?

Tags: c, sqlite

I'm writing a light, fast Gtk application small enough for an air-gapped stand-alone Rasberry Pi setup for my work colleagues to self-roster with. Output would be CSV files on a thumb-drive for my Line Manager to open in Excel. Reading and writing to .xlsx files may be a step too far for me, for now ... ^_~

Sqlite database for permanent storage.

I need to know if there's a function enabling me to systematically query the rows to copy the data into arrays (maybe structs too) for analysis in C (roster clashes, etc). I've read that Java has Cursors, what's the C equivalent?

Comment: Please make an [mcve]. I.e. provide the `.dump` of a suitably tailored toy database and show the output/result you hope to achieve.

Comment: The C equivalent of a Java database Cursor is a C database Cursor. A cursor is a "pointer" to the current record the DBMS-client is looking at. Sqlite undoubtedly has cursors in its C API.

Comment: I doubt there will be a function to copy records to rows due to allignment aspects of a C struct. You can however get a row into the cursor and then copy field-by field to your array of structs.

Comment: If you just need to do a straight dump of a table to a CSV file, the command line shell makes that trivial: https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html#csv_export

Comment: For executing queries and working with the results in C... start with https://www.sqlite.org/cintro.html

Answer (score 1):

> I need to know if there's a function enabling me to systematically query the rows to copy the data into arrays (maybe structs too) for analysis in C

There is no function to associate an entire array or struct with an SQLite row in SQLite's [C API](https://sqlite.org/cintro.html). You will need to retrieve each element of your struct or array using [`sqlite3_column_xxx()`](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/column_blob.html) (e.g. `sqlite3_column_int()` to retrieve an integer value).

Suppose, for example, you had a `struct` such as the following:

```
typedef struct {
    int employee_id;
    int day_of_month;
    int shift_no;
} roster_entry_t;
```

and an SQLite table with a matching schema, you would retrieve an array of these structs using a function such as the following:

```
int get_roster_entries(sqlite3 *db, roster_entry_t *roster, int max,
                       int *count) {
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt = NULL;
    int rc = 0;
    int i = 0;

    rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(
        db, "SELECT employee_id, day_of_month, shift_no FROM roster LIMIT ?",
        -1, &stmt, NULL);
    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to prepare SQL: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        return 1; 
    }
    rc = sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 1, max);
    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Problem setting limit: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        return 1;
    }

    do {
        roster_entry_t *entry = &roster[i++];
        rc = sqlite3_step(stmt);
        if (rc == SQLITE_DONE) {
            printf("No more rows ...\n");
            break;
        } else if (rc != SQLITE_ROW) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Problem: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db)); 
            sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
            return 1;
        }
        entry->employee_id = sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 0);
        entry->day_of_month = sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 1);
        entry->shift_no = sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 2);
    } while (i < max);
    *count = i - 1;

    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
    return 0; 
}
```

**Notes**

- Variables in your program can be associated with placeholders in your SQL using [`sqlite3_bind_xxx()`](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html).
- Even though it makes the code a lot more verbose, it is really worthwhile to check the return values of the SQLite functions.
- Array indices for `sqlite3_bind_xxx()` start at 1, while those for `sqlite3_column_xxx()` start 0 (somewhat confusingly).

Comment: That's great! Before posting I had a vague idea to list some of the meta-data about my Nursing colleagues in a struct representing them to give the Manager some relevant context, and the rest of the relevant rostering data (shift types, dates) as either small assortment of terse strings or even enumerated into integers for analysis. User input would mostly be limited to suites of dropdown or drag and drop options.